Are questions about the life history of famous cognitive scientists on topic?
We recently had a question about the cause of death of a psychology professor.
This question raised several issues. But of particular relevance for this site is whether it is on topic to ask questions about the lives of cognitive scientists.
Presumably, there are many different types of such questions, which will vary in the degree to which they relate substantive knowledge produced by the academic.
However, the general question:
What rules govern when a question about the life history of a famous cognitive scientist is on topic?

Thanks for asking this Jeromy! I wanted to but was unable at the time I saw that question.

My own comments largely align with those of @what.
There is a rich history of cognitive science that should be open for discussion.  This could relate to the evolution of our knowledge, changes in techniques over time, or how the context of a scientist's life influenced their research. That being said, I do think the question at the root of this discussion is almost certainly off-topic. The fact that Wegner conducted cognitive research does not make a discussion of his passing automatically relevant.  Further, a question that is focused on the circumstances of that passing would be difficult to justify.

I think that the site should keep the focus on the science itself, and not on its history or related sociology. So only questions that are directly related to the science should be on topic. Other question should perhaps go to history stack exchange site (which has a science tag).
